# Laravel 5 select in select query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have got a php site. I want to rewrite it in laravel 5. The problem is here:

```
    $getAllTrainings = $db->getAll('SELECT * from add_timetable WHERE active_before >= CURDATE() AND complete = ?i', 0);

        foreach ($getAllTrainings as $training) {
            $currentTraining = $db->getOne('SELECT service_id from add_people WHERE service_card = ?s AND training_id = ?s', $service_card, $training['code']);
            if($currentTraining) {
                   $reg_button = <<<ECHO BUTTON_1
            }  else {
                   $reg_button = <<<ECHO BUTTON_2
            }
            echo <<<TRAINING
        <div class="training__item" id="{$training['code']}" >
        <h3>{$training['header']}</h3>
        <p>{$training['description']}</p>
        <div class="datetime is-flex">
            <div class="date">
                {$training['date']}
            </div>
            <div class="time">
                {$training['time']}
                <div class="small">
                    {$training['place']}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {$reg_button}
    </div>
TRAINING;
        }
```

The problem is echo different buttons (query by query)

```
if($currentTraining) {
                   $reg_button = <<<ECHO BUTTON_1
            }  else {
                   $reg_button = <<<ECHO BUTTON_2
            }
```

How to do it in Laravel?

Comment: What is `<<<ECHO BUTTON_1` meant to do?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create model named 'Training' *(run command: php artisan make:model Training)*, then load the model in your controller (*use App\Training;*), and then to get the collection run:

```
$trainings = Training::where('complete', 1)->whereDate('active_date', '>=', Carbon::now()')
// note the Carbon usage, you will need to add it by adding use Carbon;

foreach($trainings as $training){
   // do something with your collection here.
}
```

Of course, you need to have the table in your database, and established connection, if you dont then you need to learn more about Migrations, make a table 'Trainings' and migrate it.